# Using ViewModel to populate razor table

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, viewmodel

I have a AcceptedTableViewModel that inherits from PendingModel (fName, lName, Unit) and AcceptedModel(TimeAccepted, TotalVotes). PendingModel and AcceptedModel both have their own sql tables.

I need to be able to use AcceptedTableViewModel as the model I'm looping through to fill a table in a razor page.

Normally I would create a

```
_dbContext.PendingModel.ToList()
```

then in my razor, loop through the PendingModel to pull all data.

AcceptedTableViewModel doesn't have a db to pull from.

How do I reference AcceptedTableViewModel in my razor to pull the data?

Comment: Could you [edit] your post with a [mre]? It's much better than _describing_ your code context.

Comment: So how's it populated?